# Crop PDF without keeping invisible content (.NET or ObjC)

Tags: .net, objective-c, pdf, itext

I'm trying to crop a PDF using .NET (using PDF4NET or iTextSharp, but not closed to these ones) or Objective-C (CGContextXXX, CGPDFXXX, etc.)... But without keeping the invisible content !

Currently, I'm able to do the crop operation using the Crop Box or a Clip Region, but all content invisible is still present in the PDF...

Is it possible ?

Thanks (and sorry, I'm french...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features.html) for this task. You could use the method [IacDocument.GetObjectsInRectangle](http://amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Amyuni_PDFCreator_IacDocument/Methods/GetObjectsInRectangle_Method.htm) to retrieve all the "graphic objects" of your interest:

> IacDocument.GetObjectsInRectangle Method
>
> The GetObjectsInRectangle method gets all the objects that are in the
> specified rectangle.

Then you can iterate all the objects in the page and delete those that you are not interested in:

```cs
//open a pdf document
document.Open (testfile,"");
IacPage page1 = document.GetPage (1);
Amyuni.PDFCreator.IacAttribute attribute = page1.AttributeByName ("Objects");
// listobj is an array list of graphic objects
System.Collections.ArrayList listobj = (System.Collections.ArrayList) attribute.Value;
foreach ( object pdfObj in listobj )
{
   // if pdfObj is not in the collection of interest
   // then call pdfObj.Delete();
}
```

**Update:**
Amyuni PDF Creator .Net version 5.0 adds a new method [IacDocument.Redact](https://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Amyuni_PDFCreator_IacDocument/Methods/IacDocument.Redact_Method.htm) which might also be helpful in this kind of scenario:

> The Redact method retrieves all the objects of the specified type in
> the specified rectangle, deletes them, and draws a solid color
> rectangle at their place.

*Disclaimer: I work for Amyuni Technologies*

Comment: Thanks.
One (more) problem: If there is a "big" object (a Line for example) that starts inside of the rectangle, but ends really far out... It will be included too, isn't it ?
Is it possible to "reduce" this object so it fits perfectly with the rectangle ?

Comment: ingham GetObjectsInRectangle allows you to choose if you want to keep the intersected items or not, but if you want to keep only a portion of each of them, then you will need to use clipping, sorry.

Comment: I'm trying your solution, I'm able to get an Array with desired IacObject, but I don't find how to copy these items in a new page (nor how to delete all other objects)...